# C# Windows Service - Default Arguments on Install

Tags: .net

My application (which is a windows service) needs one command line argument which is the location of a config file.

I want the service to be able to start automatically. Filling in the 'Startup parameters' value only applies to manually starting it and that value does not carry over after the service is stopped.

I tried manually editing the "Path to executable" in the registry but the .net service doesn't regocnise it as if it were a command line (taking the 2nd section of the path as the arguments)

Is there a way to setup a default argument on install (either using InstallUtil or any other way)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add command line parameters to your service by appending them to the ImagePath parameter value found in :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<your service>\
```

Using the [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) you can read them in your service when it gets started.

Comment: So I just use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs rather then the args parameter in OnStart?

Thanks Rick. I'll give that a shot tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

We use the app config file to do this, the service can read it's initialization options from there.

Comment: That's the thing - This is the location of the config file i'm trying to pass in.

I can't use a default config file (e.g. config.xml) because the working directory isn't where my application is as it's a windows service. The config file needs to be in the same place as the application.

Comment: If you use myapp.exe.config (by adding app.config to your project) and read the settings via `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StateServerPort"]` then this file will be read from the app directory instead of the working directory.

Comment: You can also discover the location of your executable using reflection, if you just want to find where you are running from rather than the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

did you know that if you use the service installer, you can implement this to set the registry settings based on something in your installer without needing to get the user to perform any post operation or running some batch file.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration.Install

Public Class ProjectInstaller

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Component Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add initialization code after the call to InitializeComponent

    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceInstaller1_AfterInstall(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceInstaller1.AfterInstall
'Put some code regarding your Installation specific options.
    End Sub
End Class
```