# When I try to start my Windows service, I get error number 1053

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I am trying to pass a parameter to a Windows service, when I install the service using the command prompt in given manner shown below

**d:\mypath>installutil -i service.exe -parameter**

Before installing in program.cs file I have written in the following manner

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            **string path = args[0];**              
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                **new VibrantEmail(path)** 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
```

and in service.cs page I have written this

```
**public VibrantEmail(string path)**
        {
            **data = path**
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

The thing is like when I use **static void Main(string[] args)**
in program.cs page then only I get this error, number 1053.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't provide arguments at installation step. `Installutil` expects only assembly of which installer component will be executed. You will have to use [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) to retrieve arguments in your code, then install service without providing parameters and modify its execution path based on [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124546/c-sharp-windows-service-default-arguments-on-install).